# Create a menu tab of different views

Tags: views, 7

Having 3 different view , I'm going to show them in a page as different tabs.
All of these views have exposed filter and are not completely related (one view shows users , one shows content and the last one shows taxonomy terms).
I changed the menu types in these views to menu tab and their address to "seek/VIEWNAME".

now trying to browse seek I face 404 error and browsing "seek/users" I only get the "user" view without any tabs to other views.

How can create a tab consisting menus to different views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the link about [Creating Tabbed Views](http://tewson.com/content/creating-tabbed-views-drupal-6).

For quick reference, I am copying important steps here from above link.

1. Create a view.
2. Name the path (url) to be what you want the default tab to be, for example, 'document/all'.
3. Configure your view with sorting, filtering, etc.
4. Choose 'Default menu tab' in Menu option and name it.
5. Choose 'Normal menu item' to be the parent, since this tab is linked directly from a menu, i.e. 'document'
6. Finish this first tab.
7. Create another display.
8. Name the path of this one as a tab option, like 'document/homework'.
9. Configure it.
10. Choose 'Menu tab' for this one.
11. Finish this tab.
12. Repeat (8) - (11) for more tabs.

**Note:** If you want three tabs on same page with different/same view result, then please install [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a block
2. Add the following code to the .info

   `regions[test]      = 'Test'`
3. Create test--block.tpl.php
4. Add html codes to create desired tabs in test.tpl.php
5. Add the following code to display the tab content

   ```
   <?php print views_embed_view('VIEW NAME',"block"); ?>
   ```
6. Blocks in the Region

   **Suggestion:** create tabs using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)